# The jewel's legacy (part 1)

Tags: riddle, story, geography

Here is my very first puzzle, in the form of several smaller puzzles (around 10, can be changed) linked by a story. Here is the first part, a not-so-small introduction and the first puzzle.

---

You, a member of a previously rich family, found a few weeks ago a note from your grandfather which talks about a secret hidden inside a jewel. He didn't describe how he did this, but he notes this secret is a transcription of an older secret, discovered by his ancestor and at the origin of their social advancement.

Unfortunately, after his death, all his valuables, probably including this mysterious jewel, had to be sold to pay off a debt. Your research leads you to the probable new owner of this jewel, a paranoid collector only known as "Mr. X" on markets. You only have one clue about him: he never leaves North America.
But today, you got a chance to change this.

On one auction site, Mr. X. said he will be present at a party organised by one of his friends to celebrate a new acquisition. This friend invites any people able to find the location of the party. It could be a great occasion to meet Mr. X. You can't pass on this occasion.

The first thing to do is to solve this:

"Two keys are needed to find the solution, hidden in only one sentence. This sentence:
'A right angle is needed in your mind when you'll remember the price of a great betrayal.'
With these keys and what you know about me, you'll be able to find the town of the party."

Where do you need to be to be invited to this party?

Comment: Aparantly, the price of a great betrayal is $24.99 + shipping. ( http://www.amazon.com/The-Great-Betrayal-Memoirs-Douglas/dp/1857821769)

Comment: I didn't know this. Even if it's not the betrayal I think about, I have to admit it suits the few things I said. But it's not a part of the expected answer.

Comment: @Narmer Yes, you're right... I'll fix it and review all to avoid other issues.

Comment: Hahaha. $24.99 is cheap for a great betrayal.

Comment: Is it necessary to have strong history knowledge from US or another place?

Comment: @fffred No. Not a strong knowledge (but a medium one I would said), not about history and not about a specific place or country.

Comment: @Shkeil,
can you clarify the first clue?("he never leaves North America. But today, you got a chance to change this") 
Does he never leave america except today? or are you changing the fact you only have one clue?

Comment: @Bishop I changing the fact you only have one clue. Sorry if it could be misunderstood.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think the town is

> New Orleans

Because:

> Firstly, I stole a part of [Alessandro Niciforo's](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/1877/alessandro-niciforo) [answer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/30319/9352):
>  *The great betrayal is the one done by [Judas Iscariot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Judas_Iscariot) and the price has been 30 silver coins.*
>  So knowing that the cost was **30** and the right angle is **90** degrees(we only need numbers), and that this place is somewhere in the North America, the coordinates are either **30N, 90W** or **90N, 30W**, but **90N** is the North Pole, so the only possibility is [**30N, 90W**(which is in New Orleans according to Google Maps)](https://www.google.be/maps/place/30%C2%B000'00.0%22N+90%C2%B000'00.0%22W/@30,-90.0700378,12z/)

Comment: Yes, this is it. With the right way to find it. I'll try to do the second part quickly.

Comment: @Shkeil still waiting for part 2 :)

Comment: Sorry about the delay, I got some privacy problems. It's online now.

Answer (score 3):

I feel like I'm on the right track but I'm missing something. Let's give it a shot.

> The party will be in **New Orleans**
>
>   The great betrayal is the one done by [Judas Iscariot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Judas_Iscariot) and the price has been **30** silver coins.
>
>   We found the first key, 30. The second key is the *right angle*, **90** (degrees). If we read these as GPS coordinates, arranged so that the result will be in North America, we get [30N 90W](https://www.google.it/maps/place/51%C2%B000'00.0%22N+62%C2%B000'00.0%22W/), New Orleans!
>
>   I'm leaving here my first answer, for history:
>   This price is written in Matthew 26:15 and looking at it from a *right angle* (reverse), it's 51,62. If we read these as GPS coordinates, arranged so that the result will be in North America, we get [51N 62W](https://www.google.it/maps/place/51%C2%B000'00.0%22N+62%C2%B000'00.0%22W/).--

Comment: Even if it's not the solution, your reasoning is the closest so far.

Comment: I found the solution and edited my answer. Just after editing I discovered that Novarg already found that 40 mins ago...

Comment: Maybe you'll be luckier for the next one.

Comment: ;) looking forward to it

Comment: @AlessandroNiciforo I wouldn't be able to find it without your original answer ;)

Answer (score 1):

The town of the party is

> London. The place may be the Palace of Westminster

Because

> the great betrayal is that of guy fawkes and the right angle refers to the hands on the clock face of big ben.

Comment: Is there a London in North America?

Comment: I think he is saying that he never leaves north america, except for this party

Comment: If it could be confused, I'm sorry. I wanted to said that "you" will know more about Mr. X, but Marius has right: it's in North America.

Comment: I just read my previous comment again and it sounds wrong.  Just for the record...I wasn't being snarky or anything. My question was legit an with good intentions.

Comment: @Marius:  [London, Ontario](https://www.google.ca/maps/place/London,+ON/@43.0040567,-82.0204176,8z/data=!4m2!3m1!1s0x882ef20ea88d9b0b:0x28c7d7699a056b95)

Answer (score 1):

The town of the party is

> Montgomery, Alabama

Because

> the great betrayal is that of the southern states seceding from the union and the Montgomery is close to 90 degrees longitude (and also the first capital of the confederacy)

Comment: Good try, but no. A too important part of buildings or monuments forms a distinct right angle with the ground to be really significant.

Comment: Fair enough. I went with a different direction with it

Comment: You got something, but it's not still here.

Answer (score 1):

Is it something related with

> The Jubilee Parkway (a pair of parallel viaduct bridges across MobilE BAY, in Alabama) ? And one of the synonyms for betrayal is "double-crossing", so... they would be "a great betrayal", right?

Comment: It's too lateral-thinking here. The betrayal have to be understood without thinking about another signification