# The jewel's legacy (part 2)

Tags: story, password, language

*This story begins in [The jewel's legacy (part 1)](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/30259).*

---

After some research about the host of the party, Mr. Xavier Change, you discover he has several houses or mansions, and one of them is near New Orleans. With the previous riddle, it’s enough to you to go here. You put and the notes you can find about the jewel and this secret into a suitcase and take a flight to New Orleans.

Find the party place is quite easy now you’re here. But in your search about new information about this party and their guests, Mr. Change has added something about the invitation itself.
“Unfortunately, due to some events, my guards don’t want to see a free access into the party. So I have to ask you to give to my guards a password, defined by their question. It’s our usual game, I choose to use the typed one. And since we have two major choices here, the answer will be both, no matter the order. It’s the first time I’ll use this game as a password, but I’m sure it won’t be a problem for anyone able to solve my first riddle.”
You don’t know what this game is, of course. But maybe by spying questions and answers, you will be able to find. You don’t have too much to lose after all since you are already here.

When the time has come, you decide to wait quietly near the entry. The first guests seem to be already inside. But you’re not the last, and soon more guest come.
When the guards see the first one, one of them says “Password:  5?”. The guest says “1 and 1”. You hear “Correct” and the guest enters.
For the second guest, the guard asks “Password: 37?”. The guest takes few moments and says “2 and 4”. “Correct” and he’s enters.
The next ones are a couple, talking to each other in a foreign accent when the guard interrupts them. “Password: 64?”. The man says “1 and 5”. The guard replies “Incorrect.” “What?” “It’s not the correct password, please leave”.
When they leave, you hear the woman complains “I told you it’s not the second main here, but you never listen.”
After this, a lot of guests come, and you notice every couple on question/answers:
For 3, it’s 2 and 1. 
For 81, it’s 4 and 4. 
For 19, it’s 2 and 3. 
For 50, it’s 0 and 3.
You even hear someone who seems to talk to his phone in a foreign language. When the guard asks him the password for 44, he shut down his phone and says: “I haven’t understand if I have to say 2 and 7 or 7 and 2”. The guard says: “Both are accepted. You can come in”.
Then, a second guard comes next to you. “Mister, if you want to enter, you have to go now. We will close in 2 minutes”.  Surprised, you don’t have time to react than he already joins his colleague.
Hesitantly, you walk to the entrance, a luxurious one. The first guard smiles quickly when you approach, but he remains professional when he asks to you: “Password: 13?”
What do you have to say if you want to be accepted?

---

I know it's no more than a "Security to the party" question and the last one have be rejected beacause it's was to broad. This is why I tried to be as precise, with several clues, as possible to leave only one possible answer. But I can't be sure, so I'll accept every answer which fits all attempts (or failure) AND clues, even if it's not my expected answer.

Hint

> Don't search about a math logical.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I say

> 2 and 2

Because :

> It is the number of "closed" letters when you write the number in English and French. What I call "closed" letter is a letter where a piece of white is surrounded by the line (I don't know if there is a name for that).
>  The "closed" letters are **a, e, o, p, q, d, g** and **b**. These letters count as the 1 as the others as 0.
>  
>
>  5 : 'fiv**e**' = 1 and 'cin**q**' = 1
>  37 : 'thirty s**e**v**e**n' = 2 and 'tr**e**nt**e** s**ep**t' =4
>  3 : 'thr**ee**' = 2 and 'tr**o**is'=1
>  81 : '**e**i**g**hty **o**n**e**' = 4 and '**q**u**a**tr**e**-vin**g**t-un' = 4
>  19 : 'nin**e**t**ee**n' = 3 and '**d**ix-n**e**uf" = 2
>  50 : 'fifty' = 0 and 'cin**q**u**a**nt**e**' = 3
>  44 : f**o**urty f**o**ur -> 2; **q**u**a**r**a**nt**e**-**q**u**a**tr**e** -> 7
>
>  New Orleans was a french colony, that's why French can be consider as a "major choice" of language for the puzzle.
>
>   The couple who says "1 and 5" for 64 thinks that the langugages are English and Spanish, the two main languages in the USA :
>  sixty f**o**ur -> 1
>  s**e**t**e**nt**a** y cu**a**tr**o** -> 5
>  But Spanish is not the "second main" language in New Orleans.
>
>   When the guard says 13 :
>  thirt**ee**n : 2
>  tr**e**iz**e** : 2
>  So the answer is "2 and 2"

Comment: ...and 44: f**o**urty f**o**ur -> 2; **q**u**a**r**a**nt**e**-**q**u**a**tr**e** -> 7

Comment: Even if one clue isn't used, it's the correct answer. I hope I'll be able to ask next part soon.